# What library exists to provider cross browser DOM access?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser

Recently I realised that JQuery does not promise cross browser support after they announced that JQuery 2+ will no longer support IE8 and lower. Reading their site carefully I realise now that actually this was my mistake, that JQuery is designed to simplify DOM traversal and not specifically to flatten the differences between supported browsers. As excellent as JQuery is at its job I need to look for something else.

My question is, are there other (commercial) libraries out there with the stated intention of  flattening the various DOMs?

Comment: "I realised that JQuery does not promise cross browser support" — Yes, they do. "they announced that JQuery 2+ will no longer support IE8 and lower" — They're reducing the scope of their support going forwards. Continue using 1.x if you care about IE8 and lower (which have a shrinking market share).

Comment: Voting to close as "not constructive" as this can only generate a list of options.

Comment: I didn't know that jQuery 2.x will drop support for IE8. I hope that IE8 usage will drop below 5% when jQuery 2 will be out.

Comment: @MaxArt 5% is still 1 in 20 users and for many many sites that is an awful lot of users.

Comment: @Quentin Perhaps my definition of cross-browser support is a little different to the accepted standard. Versions of IE from 6-8 are not changing their behaviour and are still relatively common. My reason for using JQuery was to be able to create sites that would work with all the browsers they listed. I did not care about new features for new browsers so long as the old features work with old and new browsers.

Comment: @naskew — So use jQuery 1.x, which will be supported by the jQuery team and will support old-IE. If you don't want the new features in new browsers, don't use the new major revision of the library that focuses on them.

Comment: @naskew The current jQuery version is 1.7.2. What you're talking about is a plan for the far future, for version 2. jQuery supports old IEs, so you can use it. No need to worry. A lot of people use it. Don't panic. Please read Quentin's comments carefully.

Answer (score 1):

If JQuery and JQuery2+ api are not different, you can use [google's javascript loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/) to fetch the one that fit a given browser version. I thing GWT will keep support for ie < 8 but is not as lighweight as Jquery :)

Comment: I'll take a look at GWT and see what they claim for browser support but that might be an option for me.